# Why is this variable being set to false?

Tags: c++, boolean

I have a function that is supposed to check the possible answers to a certain coordinate on a sudoku board.  I just need you to focus on the variable `first` however.  For some reason `first` is set to false and I have no idea why.

**Function:**

```
void displayPossible(int board[][9], char input[], int &row, int &col)
{
  bool first = true;                          // variable instantiated and set to true
  cout << "First " << first << endl;

  bool possible[9];                           // I dont touch `first` at all
  computeValues(board, possible, row, col);   // between these two lines..

  cout << "First " << first << endl;          // by this point it is false. WHY!?
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Possible: ";
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    cout << possible[i];
  cout << endl;

  cout << "First " << first << endl;
  cout << "The possible values for '" << input << "' are: ";
  // if I say 'first = true' right here, i get my expected outcome
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
      if(possible[i] && first == true)
        {
          first = false;
          cout << i;
        }
      else if(possible[i] && first == false)
        cout << ", " << i;

      else
        ;
    }
  cout << endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
First 1
First 0

Possible: 000010001
First 0
The possible values for 'd1' are: , 4, 8
```

**Compute Values:**

```
void computeValues(int board[][9], bool possible[], int row, int col)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    possible[i] = true;

  for(int iRow = 0; iRow < 9; iRow++)
    possible[board[iRow][col]] = false;

  for(int iCol = 0; iCol < 9; iCol++)
    possible[board[row][iCol]] = false;

  for(int iRow = 0; iRow < 2; iRow++)
    for(int iCol = 0; iCol < 2; iCol++)
      possible[board[row/3*3 + iRow][col/3*3 + iCol]] = false;

  if(board[row][col] != 0)
    possible[board[row][col]] = true;
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly because `computeValues` has a bug that overwrites memory it should not touch, and this affects `first` because it's located on the stack next to `possible`. But it's impossible to say without the code for `computeValues`.

Comment: You're probably accidentally overwriting it in `computeValues` e.g. by overflowing `possible[]`. Can we see `computeValues`?

Comment: Would you please post the code of computeValues

Comment: @kol @jon @rup `computeValues()` has been added.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Eegabooga: That doesn't help that much because it turns out that `computeValues` writes depending on the values inside `board`, which we still don't see. But I think you have enough information to debug the issue now.

Comment: We also need to know the sizes of board, its elements, and the values row and col, at the moment when computeValues is called.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely is that `computeValues` has a buffer overrun which is corrupting the value of `first`. One obvious possibility is that it writes to `possible` with an out-of-bounds index. Since `possible` and `computeValues` are quite probably next to each other on the stack, that seems a likely explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`computeValues` must be writing beyond the end of one of the arrays you pass to it (most likely `possible`). This is corrupting the stack, overwriting the value of `first`, and possibly causing other less obvious mayhem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like ComputeValues is accessing a pointer that points (erroneously) to &first.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to a bug in `possibleValues()` that overwrites the value of `first` in memory.